# Formula how to add the two quantity from the earliest date

Tags: excel-formula

I want to look for the nearest exp date 'Cell G" and quantity 'Cell H' from the left data.
With refer to the sample screenshot,

1. to fine the nearest exp date: I using xlookup to return earliest date by matching with the material. Return value 04-Mar-22.
2. to find the nearest exp quantity: if using xlookup will only return the first quantity which is 7. But, actually there are two line with same batch D261205L and same exp date 04-Mar-22, is there any formula can get the result of adding that two quantity?

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

First, lookup the earliest date for the material

```
=XLOOKUP(F2,A2:A9,D2:D9,"")
```

which looks up the value `F2` (in this case `m2`) in the range `A2:A9` and returns the corresponding value from the range `D2:D9`. This goes into cell `G2`.

In cell `H2`, write

```
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER(A2:D9,(D2:D9=G2)*(A2:A9=F2),""),,3))
```

which filters the range `A2:D9` for multiple conditions, the date and then the material. The `INDEX` function slices the returned array for the `qty` column (which is column 3 in `A2:D9`), and the `SUM` function then sums the filtered column.

Then wrap the whole thing up with `IFERROR`

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(FILTER(A2:D9,(D2:D9=G2)*(A2:A9=F2),""),,3)),"")
```

which returns the empty string if any of the criteria aren't present.

Comment: Thanks for participate. The formula above is sum up all the quantity under same material. But I want to know how many total quantity that have earliest expiration date for that material. If using manual, the value for G3 = 04 March 2022, H3 = 140 , hence both are interrelated.

Comment: @shirleyMY; how does your lookup know how not to return row 10?

Comment: G3 column - I think system will pick up the first data which is the earliest date. Perhaps that should be other formula which is MinIF? I not good in formula therefore if there is suitable formula apply for G3 and H3 would be appreciate.

Comment: The Sum +Index+Filter working fine. Its also will return "#ref!" when the column G2 date is blank, because not all will have date. Possible to return 0 or blank if the date is blank ?

Comment: @shirleyMY; `IFERROR` returns either the normal value if OK, or an alternative if there is an error.

Comment: Finally tested , it's worked ! Thank you :) on Top of that, I have problem with MINIFS with two condition, if not meet the criteria return blank. But seem like cannot have blank.